# Where can I find a list of abbreviations used in tree diagrams of sentences?

Tags: syntax, resource-request

When I visited the EzTreeSee website at http://eztreesee.coli.uni-saarland.de/ and entered "Mary had a little lamb," I immediately encountered abbreviations that I had never seen before, to wit...

NNP  VBD  JJ   NN

I've searched the net in vain for the meanings of these abbreviations.  But that doesn't mean that there isn't a link.

So where can I find a list of abbreviations for the names of constituents identified in phrase-structure grammar trees?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We created eztreesee so that rank beginners can try out sentences without having to install parsers, models, etc. on their own computers. [The backend](https://bitbucket.org/pnr/depgrapher) runs entirely off the Stanford Parser. And therefore, what you see there are Penn Treebank tags.

The official documentation for PTB tags is [this weird PostScript file](ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/treebank/doc/tagguide.ps.gz); you might prefer [this quickref](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/amalgam/tagsets/upenn.html).